# My HTTP response does not have transfer-encoding chunked even after not setting content-length header in http request

Tags: http, chunked

I read in some articles that if we do not set content-length header in http request,we get the http response in chunks.(Transfer-encoding:chunked which is choosen by server implicitly in such case).In my java code I did not set content-length header.Still I am getting content-length header in my response instead of chunked transfer.please help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean "do not set content-length header in http *response*".

Anyway, a servlet engine is free not to use chunked encoding if it can determine the length of the reponse before sending it.

Comment: I want chunked transfer encoding in my response.I read in some article that If we do not set content-length in our program while sending request then the server will respond with transfer encoding chunked.So in my Program I did not set content-length filed.Still I am not getting transfer encoding as chunked

Comment: Well, what you read is partly wrong. Sorry about that.

*Why* do you want chunked transfer encoding?

Comment: In my applicaiton I want to get the size of each chunk that I am getting in my http response.For that I need response in the form of chunked encoding.

Comment: If the response doesn't use chunked encoding, then you won't get any chunks (or exactly one chunk, if you want to see it that way). Why does it matter?